# How can I find out the size of all the pdfs in a directory?

Tags: windows-7, file-management

I have a folder with multiple subfolders. In Windows 7, I'd like to be able to find out the total size of all of the pdfs (files with extension .pdf)  in that folder.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Navigate to the topmost directory you want to start the search from, use *.pdf as the search filter in the top right of explorer and hit enter. After the search finishes, select all results with Ctrl-A and hit properties.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the main folder (the root of all the subfolders), you can type *.pdf in the search box (top right corner), then select all the PDFs, right click -> Properties.

That should show you the total file size of all the selected files.

Answer (score 0):

View by type.
Select 1st pdf
scroll to last PDF
hold shift and select last pdf.
now all pdf should be selected.
Right click on any of them and properties.
If a lot it will continue counting until stops.